# sbt run error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sbt

I'm writing a spark scala application with SBT and when I simply run it as scala application, it shows the output. When I do `sbt package` it downloads all dependencies and shows **success**. When I do `sbt run`, it throws error:

```
[info] Running main.scala.com.sntz.omega.Test 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils.getDefaultRetryPolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:408)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:314)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:668)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:604)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:148)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3354)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:226)
[error]     at main.scala.com.sntz.omega.Test$.main(Test.scala:29)
[error]     at main.scala.com.sntz.omega.Test.main(Test.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]     at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
[error]     at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:77)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]     at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-executorManagement, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-shared, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-appStatus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:73)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread spark-listener-group-appStatus
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread spark-listener-group-shared
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
18/06/25 11:51:24 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread spark-listener-group-executorManagement
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply$mcJ$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:82)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]     at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:124)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1185)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1180)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:366)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:289)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 25 Jun, 2018 11:51:24 AM
sbt:OmegaTest> 18/06/25 11:53:24 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
```

My build.sbt content:

```
name := "OmegaTest"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.1.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1"
```

So, how to resolve this problem. I don't really understand the reason behind this?

Thanks

Comment: This is most likely a conflict between hadoop dependencies. Do you get any warnings from SBT, like "Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:"?

Comment: after creating a jar don't you have to run spark program with spark-submit? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the below line to build.sbt, I resolved the issue

> fork in run := true

Comment: I'm getting this error when sbt compile doesnt show any warning or error *  $ sbt run throws an exception  Exception in thread "sbt-bg-threads-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)